# Reference to stopped workin in ms access-Database

Tags: vba, ms-access

I maintain a couple of ms-access databases and after an ms-office update on monday the split function didn't work any longer in one of them. A compile error was prompt: " wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" a quick search suggested to replace Split with VBA.Split which worked. So i added the library reference in front of every function call in this database and the code is working again.

Strangely only one of the databases was affected, however i have development versions on 2 different machines (synched via a vcs plugin and gitlab server) and it stopped working on both of them independently. one of them has a access 2016 professional plus version the other one has an office 365 version.

The references don't show any missing libraries and while i am relieved to get them up and running again like this i am startled at what has happened and wonder how i can properly check the references in vba. I would appreciate if anyone could suggest a reliable way to check what went wrong and how i could possibly fix the reference.

Comment: That means `Split` from the `VBA` library is shadowed elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Oh thanks BigBen, you are totally right, I feel silly now.

I had created a Split function in another module and was absent minded as to name it differently. It had nothing to do with the Office Update.

Thanks a lot!